# Apache FOP how to limit character length with line break / where to implement the function needed

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation, apache-fop

XML to PDF conversion using Apache FOP;

How to implement a function to limit the character length of a charsequence (e.g. 0123_455-678) in a specific table box?

I got the problem, that one part of the table overlaps another one due to the length of data input with no spaces/regular separation in between.
I would like to implement a function to linebreak the charsequence at a specific length, but don't actually know at which spot i have to place it.

Comment: The usual suggestion is to [insert a zero-width space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18317781/4453460) either after every character or where you would like a line break to happen, and then let FOP do the rest of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Needed to implement a template which is called at the table content in the layout.xml